# Plane-Plane Intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you find the equation of the line that is given by the intersection of these planes:

x+y=2

z=3

(Keep in mind that im a beginner in this subject, but i'm looking forward to learn)

Comment: I don't know how far along you are in your studies - but if you think about the geometry you can see that the direction of the line is perpendicular to the normals to each plane. Find the two normal vectors. Then find their cross product to find a vector perpendicular to both.

Comment: What do you mean by “the equation of the line?” What form are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you Ethan, that helped a lot! On the other hand, sorry if i didn't express myself correctly. I was looking for the vector form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  line is the solution of the system
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=2\\
z=3
\end{cases}
$$
that we can write in the form:

$$
\begin{cases}
x=2-y\\
z=3\\
y=t
\end{cases}
$$
where $y=t \in \mathbb{R}$ means that $y$ can have any real value.
reordering the system we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=2-t\\
y=t\\
z=3
\end{cases}
$$
that, in vector form,  becomes the **[equation of the line in vector form](https://scientificsentence.net/Equations/CalculusIII/index.php?key=yes&Integer=3D_equations_lines)** :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\0\\3
\end{bmatrix}
+t
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$